# Select column based on input enum parameter

Tags: c#, linq, select, design-patterns, enums

I have table with columns

```
Id | UserId | GoogleEnabled | FacebookEnabled | TwitterEnabled
```

In code I want to select value of `{provider}Enabled` value - `true/false` base on input enum

```
enum Provider
{
   Google,
   Facebook,
   Twitter
}

private async Task CheckSettingsAsync(ISeedSession<IDbSession> seedSession, IUserInfo user, Provider provider){
...
var userSettingsTask = seedSession
                .Query<UserSettings>()
                .Where(us => us.UserId == user.UserId)
                .Select(us => us.GoogleEnabled) // if provider value is "Google"
                .SingleAsync();
...
}
```

Is there any pattern/solution better than create some `switch` to select my value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build expression `us => us.GoogleEnabled` manually, like this:

```
var argument = Expression.Variable(typeof(UserSettings));
// assuming `provider` is enum with values "Google" etc
var accessor = (Expression<Func<UserSettings, bool>>) Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(argument, provider.ToString() + "Enabled"), argument);
```

And then use it like this:

```
var userSettingsTask = seedSession
   .Query<UserSettings>()
   .Where(us => us.UserId == user.UserId)
   .Select(accessor) // < here
   .SingleAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, this one can be as solution, but I'm afraid if someone creates column that aren't from this template `{provider}Enabled`.

Comment: It's not clear what your concern is. Your provider has values "Google", "Facebook", "Twitter" and you have corresonding Enabled columns - what could go wrong?

Comment: If you mean that someone might add new value to enum for which there is no "ProviderEnabled" column - well it will throw an exception but what other outcome would you expect?

Comment: I realise that it's not according to YAGNI principle, but... In case I have enum value GooglePlus, and in table only GoogleEnabled... but for app logic they are related...

Comment: Well then before building this expression check if your enum is in the range of valid values and if not - don't build expression and do whatever is suitable (not sure what is suitable in this case though - I guess you will still throw an exception). And if you want to return "GoogleEnabled" for provider "GooglePlus" - well you have to implement that logic yourself, but it's much more simple still than duplicating your whole query multiple times.

Comment: I've added custom attribute to map enum values with table columns... For me this gives more confidence :). Everything else is your sample code.